# how to implement conditional pattern matching on multiple elements in Scala/Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-science

I'm writing a method that classifies elements in a time series based on when I see a unique label in a range. For example, I have an orange, an apple, and a pear, and I see the oranges, apples, and pears at different time intervals throughout the day. Based on a combination of those time intervals, I'm classifying the fruit into labeled baskets.

I have an RDD that is composed of a tuple, (fruit, hour). My plan was to build an accumulator that increments based on how many times the fruit meets the hourly conditions.

```
var labelAccum = sc.accumulator(0)

countedData.map(x => iterator(x)).filter(_.equals("label")).collect().foreach(x => labelAccum += 1)
```

The full definition returns `Map("label" -> labelAccum.value)`, which represents a mapping of the labeled basket and the count of fruit in that basket. It works the just fine for one condition, however there's an issue when multiple conditions are added. Here is the iterator(x) which used pattern matching to bin the fruit into the corresponding time slots:

```
def iterator(x: (fruit, hour)): String = {

x.fruit match {
  case fruit if (6 until 10 contains x.hour) || (16 until 20 contains x.hour) => "label" }
}
```

So for a fruit to be labeled as "label", it needs to satisfy both conditions. However, the definition only reads one (fruit,hour) at a time. In order to match each condition, I need to read all the hours a fruit owns, and label them if any of the hours that fruit owns matches a time interval.
Is there a way to accomplish this with pattern matching? There are enumerative/imperative methods and ways to conditionally trigger the iterator with an RDD that's already filtered, but I'm curious if there's an elegant solution that is compatible with pattern matching.

Comment: Performance aside shouldn't `(6 until 10 contains x.hour) && (16 until 20 contains x.hour)` be always false?

Comment: it should, but maybe the question can be rephrased to this: what steps and changes upstream of the match statement could make this return true? Ideally it would read all the hours for each fruit and make a decision to match based on the whole set of hours, not each hour one-by-one.

Comment: Use logical disjunction?

Comment: it's actually rewritten with disjunction in our codebase as `(6 until 10 contains x.hour) || (16 until 20 contains x.hour)`. Maybe to reduce confusion I should revise the question with this, but it still doesn't get around the issue that the pattern match statement is categorizing one (fruit, hour) at a time and the label only makes sense if the fruit shows up in both time intervals, an && statement.

Comment: put another way, the conditions for a fruit to be put into the "MorningAndEvening" basket require two tuples, (fruit, hourMorning) and (fruit, hourEvening). The problem is the iterator only reads one (fruit,hour) at a time, not multiple hours associated with each fruit.

Comment: OK, so how about grouping records first?

Comment: good idea... that's probably what we'll end up doing, then calling this method for each group. I just wanted to see if there was anything with pattern matching that could support something like that in one step.

Comment: thanks for the help!